# What does "Combined" expression mean in derived column transform

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS and trying to analyze an existing package. In the dervied column transformation component, there is a derived column with expression set to "Combined". Per online resources, I understand that expressions can be functions but what does "Combined" mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined is an Input Column to derived column transformation. The Expression is referring to an Input Column which is making another copy of Combined Column.